# NetworkFirst cache strategy not saving the html content of an url

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am first time using serviceworker using workbox, have no prior experience. I want when a user visits a url, the corresponding html must be saved to cache, so when the app is offline, the content of the url serves from the cache. But I don't see the content in the cache from browser devtool. What am I missing here?

```
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { precacheAndRoute } from "workbox-precaching";
import {skipWaiting} from 'workbox-core';
import {NetworkFirst, CacheFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

// ...

function jsonResponse(value) {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(value), {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    status: 202,
  });
}

console.log("Workbox is loaded");

skipWaiting();


/* injection point for manifest files.  */
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

const pagesCache = new NetworkFirst({
  cacheName: 'pages-cache',
});

registerRoute(
  new RegExp("/projects/[-a-z0-9]+/edit$"),
  args => {
    console.log('Got in here..');
    return pagesCache.handle(args);
  }
);
```

so when I go to offline I see.

[image: pwa]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mixing both precaching and runtime caching parts from the Workbox library. Some parts of it might work, some not.

By saying *"I want when a user visits a url, the corresponding html must be saved to cache, so when the app is offline, the content of the url serves from the cache."* it seems that you want what is called a **network first caching strategy**. The simplest configuration for that using Workbox would be:

```
import {registerRoute} from 'workbox-routing';
import {NetworkFirst} from 'workbox-strategies';

registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/'),
  new NetworkFirst()
);
```

More info about the strategy here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache

I also suggest you to read a primer on Service Workers themselves. You may find one eg. here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/